# Is it okay to inherit classes in java even if it is not meant for that job

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, wicket

At my office we work with Java, Apache Wicket. Now those familiar with Wicket might know about 
the `SpringBean` annotation. For those who don't, you can think of it as Wicket's way to communicate with Spring. When a class is inheriting a wicket class like `WebPage` or `Panel`, spring is dependencies are automatically injected. But there is method to specifically tell Spring to inject dependency if it is not a subclass of a wicket component which is

```
Injector.get().inject(this);
```

It works like a swiss knife.

Now lets get to the point. Recently I saw my colleague working on a class that works with databases (and is absolutely independent of wicket) he was complaining about getting a NullPointer, I told him that he was using `SpringBean` annotation & since he was not using wicket class a parent class, he would have to tell spring about injection, or use the swiss knife.

Instead he simply made the class extend `WebPage` class which represents a WebPage. When I told him that it was not correct way, as the class has nothing to do with WebPage class, he said that it was okay as it made the thing work and he would also be using it everywhere else.

My question is that is it correct to extend a class even if it is not made for that stuff?

Comment: Explain to your colleague what wonderful fun he will have if he will ever have to revisit this project after a break.

Comment: If your company has code reviews, bring this up with another senior.  The practice of breaking convention for "just working" code is a very, very scary precedent.

Comment: We have reviews one on one with our boss, as we are a startup, will see what I can do

Comment: Well, WebPage probably extends something, if you could find some common ancestor which would work as well in this case but wouln't have anything to do with web pages that would be a better solution.

Comment: So you can "see" the web-layer from your database layer? How about proper project setup first :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class should extend only if it has **"is a"** relationship with the class.  A good explanation of "is a" relationship taken from http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php#sthash.sOckIrpz.dpuf

> In object oriented programming, the concept of IS-A is a totally based
>   on Inheritance, which can be of two types Class Inheritance or
>   Interface Inheritance. It is just like saying "A is a B type of
>   thing". For example, Apple is a Fruit, Car is a Vehicle etc.
>   Inheritance is uni-directional. For example House is a Building. But
>   Building is not a House.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I can persuade him to approach the problem correctly instead of extending classes without thinking..

Answer (score 1):

```
class Fruit{

}

class Apple extends Fruit{
   //as it is a fruit
}

class Potato extends Fruit{
   //No it is not a fruit so it should not extend it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not, it's decisions like that, that come back and hurt you later on. This guy does realise that the decision to use it everywhere else actually makes things worse not better.

You need to pick someone out as code policeman for the project, personally I wouldn't recommend any one of this level of competence for the role.